# What is the difference between these two recursive ocaml functions?

Tags: recursion, stack, overflow, ocaml

```
let rec x1() = x1();()
let rec x2() = x2();;
```

Calling x1();; generates a stack overflow whereas calling x2();; causes the program to run indefinitely. What is the difference between the 2 functions?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
let rec x1() = x1();()
```

This function is not tail recursive. It calls itself x1(); and when this call returns, the function will return a unit ().

```
let rec x2() = x2();;
```

This function is calling itself at the very end; therefore the compiler can perform tail-call optimization - which will mean that the recursive function calls will never use up all the stack space.

This page explains tail recursion: http://ocaml.org/learn/tutorials/if_statements_loops_and_recursion.html#Tailrecursion - It is a fundamental technique used by functional programming languages so that we can use recursion for implementing loops without running out of memory.

I first learnt about the process stack when I read [Smashing The Stack For Fun And Profit](http://www.phrack.org/issues.html?issue=49&id=14#article); I still think that it has the best description of what the process stack is all about.